# Scaling a UIView along one direction with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

In my app I have a draggable `UIView` to which I have added a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. Following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial) tutorial, as default the view is scaled along both x and y directions. Is it possibile to scale along only one direction using one finger? I mean, for example, I tap the `UIView` both with thumb and index fingers as usual but while I'am holding the thumb I could move only the index finger in one direction and then the `UIView` should scale along that dimension depending on the direction in which the index moves.

Actually, I have achieved this by adding pins to my `UIView` like the following:

[image]

I was just thinking my app might be of better use using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.

I hope I have explained myself, if you have some hints or tutorial or documentation to link to me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)` update only one axis: X or Y with `recognizer.scale` and keep the other one `1.0f`

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy)
```

In order to know which axis you should scale, you need to do some math to see the angle between two fingers of a gesture and based on the angle to decide which axis to scale.

Maybe something like

```
enum Axis {
    case X
    case Y
}

func axisFromPoints(p1: CGPoint, _ p2: CGPoint) -> Axis {
    let absolutePoint = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
    let radians = atan2(Double(absolutePoint.x), Double(absolutePoint.y))

    let absRad = fabs(radians)

    if absRad > M_PI_4 && absRad < 3*M_PI_4 {
        return .X
    } else {
        return .Y
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but to do that I should also know which direction the index finger (the thumb is still) is moving towards...for example, if the index finger is moving towards right I should increment x, if it's moving towards left I should decrement x... do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I have just read your update...it sounds interesting. Please, would you be more specific/clear?